# Magento 1.9 - Upload file from Product View page

Tags: magento-1.9, file-upload, varien-file-uploader

I have this code to upload file/image but don't know in which file I need to add this code to work.

```
public function saveAction() {
if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
    if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {
            try {
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'));
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);                   
                $newDir = "YOUR_DIRECTORY_TO_UPLOAD";

                $newdirPath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . "YOUR_DIRECTORY_TO_UPLOAD";

                if (!file_exists($newdirPath)) {
                    mkdir($newdirPath, 0777);
                }

                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $newDir . DS;
                $resizedPath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $newDir;
                $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['image']['name']);
                $uploadedimage = $uploader->getUploadedimage();
                $_imgUrl = $resizedPath . $uploadedimage;

            } catch (Exception $e) {

            }
            $data['image'] = $uploader->getUploadedimage();
        }
    $model = Mage::getModel('menu/menu');
    $model->setData($data)
    ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

    try {

        $model->save();
        $menu_id = $model->getId();
        if(isset($data['links'])){
            $customers = Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput($data['links']['customers']); //Save the array to your database

            $collection = Mage::getModel('menu/grid')->getCollection();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('menu_id',$menu_id);
            foreach($collection as $obj){
                $obj->delete();
            }
            foreach($customers as $key => $value){
                $model2 = Mage::getModel('menu/grid');
                $model2->setMenuId($menu_id);
                $model2->setCustomerId($key);
                $model2->setPosition($value['position']);
                $model2->save();
            }
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('menu')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
            return;
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
        return;
    }
}
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('menu')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

}

In which file I can place this code to work?

Comment: This should be in controller file or model where controller this method in model .. basically at the action of your form submit .. if you can share your module code here can tell where exactly

Comment: I don't understand.I want to upload file in directory when click add to cart.Need detail to achieve this.

Comment: Form action:
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>

& add to cart button

<button name="cart_btn" class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="button" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><i class="icon-basket"></i>Add to Cart</button>

Comment: you will need a custom module to achieve that functionality ... also you would need a form to upload the file right ? this code would be at submit action of that code

Comment: No it has to be a different form not this add to cart form

Comment: Getting Array after print $params in an observer
`Array
(
    [uenc] => aHR0cHM6Ly9wZXJzb25hbGlzZWRiaXJ0aGRheWJhbm5lcnMuY29tL2luZGV4LnBocC9sZXZpcy1weXJhbWlkLmh0bWw_X19fU0lEPVUmY3VycmVuY3k9R0JQ
    [product] => 1
    [form_key] => oDFAUm2LSnseQjvO
    [related_product] => 
    [tprice] => 19.44
    [options] => Array
        ( [4] => 2ft x 6ft
            [8] => foot
            [3] => 50cm
       )
 [options_2_file] => Array
        (
            [0] => coat-icon.png
            [1] => dress-icon.png
        )

    [options_2_file_action] => save_new
    [qty] => 1
)`

Comment: using "sales_quote_add_item" event, getting above commented data when add to cart

Comment: you can use this code with your data

Comment: Above array print just images name, should be with full downloadable link in quote item table and order item table in DB.